# Query Checking for Existence - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to to test to see if an email address exists in my database by running a query check.

I can connect to the database fine.

However no matter what, even if the email exists it returns "doesn't exist".

```
<?php

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//Setup
require_once('SB_Constants.php');
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


//Connect to the database
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
$connection = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, SAVE_USERNAME, SAVE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);

// check the connection was successful
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    die(FailedToAccessDatabase . ". Failed to connect to Database");
} else {
    echo "Connection Success!";
}


//Query Check
$assessorEmail = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email_address FROM assessorID WHERE email_address = 'ryan@ablah.com'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query_identifier) == 0) {
    die(UnregisteredAssessor . ". Doesn't Exist");
} else {

    // Exists 
    echo "Exists getting ace id.";

    //Get the assessor ID
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ace_id FROM assessorID WHERE email_address = 'ryan@blah.com'");
    echo $result;
}
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Any ideas of the problem? :)

Comment: There is an "i" missing: mysql_num_rows

Comment: You're mixing mysql_* functions with mysqli_* functions

Comment: `$query_identifier` is never declared

Comment: @colburton Sharp eyes!, just corrected - however still having problems

Comment: If you open up a different tool (like, if you can use phpMyAdmin or the MySQL Workbench tool) and run the query, do you get a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various mistakes. Fix:

```
$assessorEmail = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ace_id,email_address FROM assessorID WHERE email_address = 'ryan@ablah.com'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($assessorEmail) == 0) {
    die(UnregisteredAssessor . ". Doesn't Exist");
} else {

    // Exists 
    echo "Exists getting ace id.";

    //Get the assessor ID
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($assessorEmail);
    echo $result['ace_id'];
}
```

Comment: I'll comment on this instead of finishing mine. `mysqli_num_rows()` was checking an undefined variable `$query_identifier`.

Comment: @colburton No Idea but you are correct, Thankyou so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `mysqli_num_rows($query_identifier)` is accessing an undefined variable instead of `$assessorEmail`.

Additionally, you only need one query if you just want the `ace_id`:

```
$assessorEmail = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ace_id FROM assessorID WHERE email_address = 'ryan@ablah.com'");
```

If `mysqli_num_rows($assessorEmail)` returns a row, than the email exists and you already have the `ace_id`

```
while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($assessorEmail) = $row) {
  echo $result['ace_id'];
}
```